# Check if a field is suppressed - Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula field 'stock' and database field

{LigneBonLivraison.Quantite}. What i want is to assign a value to 'stock' if

{LigneBonLivraison.Quantite} is supressed.

I tried this code in 'stock' formula field:

```
    if isnull({LigneBonLivraison.Quantite})then
       formula = {Article.StockActuel}
    end if
```

But this code gives me this error:
[image]

So how to check if {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite} is suppressed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your condition is supressed then why are you checking `IsNull` and also can you transalate the error?

Comment: Error translation: This field name is unknown....error in formula stock 'if isnull({LigneBonLivraison.Quantite})then'

Comment: {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite} is suppressed and it has its own formula, but i need to give a value '{Article.StockActuel}' to formula field 'stock' if {LigneBonLivraison.Quantite} is suppressed